# max-width none for those browsers which supports viewport units

Tags: css

I'm designing responsive website using viewport units and now I have an issue regarding max-width. See below for example:

```
.container{
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1024px;
   /*now I want to override max-width to none if viewport unit is supported*/
   max-width: none;
}
```

But it will override to other browsers to which doesn't support viewport units.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to use max-width: none; for only those browsers which supports viewport units (using css).

Though you can trick for your layout by using max-width in viewport unit like below:

```
.container{
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1024px;
   max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: but how about if the content has a width of over 100%?

Comment: @DanielCheung Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: @DanielCheung Then you can use greater than 100vw